# webdriverio Error: Could not request headers from chromedriver_mac64.zip: Error: read ECONNRESET - Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, wdio-v4

I am writing some tests in webdriverio for one of the apps. I start the selenium server and run the following command

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js
```

When I run this on my old windows computer it works just fine, now that I have got a new mac, it fails. The following is the stack trace

```
A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Could not request headers from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_mac64.zip: Error: read ECONNRESET
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/fdfgd/Desktop/test_scripts/test/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:552:8)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at Request.onRequestError (/Users/v6x5932/Desktop/test_scripts/test/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)

Continue...
Wrote xunit report "WDIO.xunit.chrome.0-0.xml" to [./test/reports].


0 passing (1.50s)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@1.0.0 run-wdio-tests: `wdio wdio.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@1.0.0 run-wdio-tests script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dsfaf/.npm/_logs/2019-09-05T11_55_52_274Z-debug.log
```

Here is my wdio.conf.js file

```
exports.config = {

    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
    // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
    // from which `wdio` was called. Notice that, if you are calling `wdio` from an
    // NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) then the current working
    // directory is where your package.json resides, so `wdio` will be called from there.
    //
    specs: [
        './test/specs/*.js'
    ],
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
    // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
    // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
    // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
    //
    // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
    // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
    // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
    // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
    // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
    // from the same test should run tests.
    //
    maxInstances: 10,
    //
    // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
    // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
    // https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator
    //
    capabilities: [{
        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 5,
        //
        browserName: 'chrome',
        proxy: {
            proxyType: "MANUAL",
            httpProxy: "domain:port",
            // sslProxy: "domain:port"
        }
    }],
    //
    // ===================
    // Test Configurations
    // ===================
    // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
    //
    // By default WebdriverIO commands are executed in a synchronous way using
    // the wdio-sync package. If you still want to run your tests in an async way
    // e.g. using promises you can set the sync option to false.
    sync: true,
    //
    // Level of logging verbosity: silent | verbose | command | data | result | error
    logLevel: 'silent',
    //
    // Enables colors for log output.
    coloredLogs: true,
    //
    // Warns when a deprecated command is used
    deprecationWarnings: true,
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
    bail: 0,
    //
    // Saves a screenshot to a given path if a command fails.
    screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if Selenium Grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Initialize the browser instance with a WebdriverIO plugin. The object should have the
    // plugin name as key and the desired plugin options as properties. Make sure you have
    // the plugin installed before running any tests. The following plugins are currently
    // available:
    // WebdriverCSS: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss
    // WebdriverRTC: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverrtc
    // Browserevent: https://github.com/webdriverio/browserevent
    // plugins: {
    //     webdrivercss: {
    //         screenshotRoot: 'my-shots',
    //         failedComparisonsRoot: 'diffs',
    //         misMatchTolerance: 0.05,
    //         screenWidth: [320,480,640,1024]
    //     },
    //     webdriverrtc: {},
    //     browserevent: {}
    // },
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
    services: ['selenium-standalone'],
    //
    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
    // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
    // see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/frameworks.html
    //
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'mocha',
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/dot.html
    reporters: ['junit','allure'],
    reporterOptions: {
        junit: {
            outputDir: './test/reports'
        },
        allure: {
            outputDir: 'allure-results'
        }
    },

    //
    // Options to be passed to Mocha.
    // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
    * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
    * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
    */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
    * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
    */
    // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
    * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
    * @param {String} commandName hook command name
    * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
    */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },

    /**
    * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
    * @param {Object} suite suite details
    */
    // beforeSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
    * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) or a step (in Cucumber) starts.
    * @param {Object} test test details
    */
    // beforeTest: function (test) {
    // },
    /**
    * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before calling
    * beforeEach in Mocha)
    */
    // beforeHook: function () {
    // },
    /**
    * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite ends (e.g. runs after calling
    * afterEach in Mocha)
    */
    // afterHook: function () {
    // },
    /**
    * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) or a step (in Cucumber) ends.
    * @param {Object} test test details
    */
    // afterTest: function (test) {
    // },
    /**
    * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
    * @param {Object} suite suite details
    */
    // afterSuite: function (suite) {
    // },

    /**
    * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
    * @param {String} commandName hook command name
    * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
    * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
    * @param {Object} error error object if any
    */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
    * the test.
    * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
    */
    // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
    */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit.
    * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    */
    // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities) {
    // }
}
```

I have tried the follwing approaches in the wdio.conf.js file

Approach 1: Lower case manual

```
 proxy: {
        proxyType: "manual",
        httpProxy: "http://domain:port"
    }
```

Approach 2: Upper case manual

```
 proxy: {
        proxyType: "MANUAL",
        httpProxy: "http://domain:port"
    }
```

Approach 3: proxy with http://

```
 proxy: {
        proxyType: "MANUAL",
        httpProxy: "http://domain:port"
    }
```

Approach 4: proxy without http://

```
 proxy: {
        proxyType: "MANUAL",
        httpProxy: "http://domain:port"
    }
```

Can you let me know what can the issue be, I also tried adding proxy to the terminal session and its still the same

Comment: I was using webdriver 4, once I updated to webdriver 5, everything started working. I did not even had to use proxies

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Could not request headers from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_mac64.zip: Error: read ECONNRESET
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.43*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Presumably you are using the latest *chrome= 76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.43* and the *Chrome Browser v76.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: I tried the above but could not fix it. I am doing this in Nodejs and npm automatically installs the required chrome, firefox drivers. I was using webdriver 4 and when I upgraded it to webdriver 5, it fixed it.

Comment: @user1707141 I don't work with `wdio-v4` or `wdio-v5` but the issue from the log messages were clear to me. I thought I could help hence the answer.

Comment: Got it, yea the logging messages are misleading